# Android : stroke in a shape create a margin of the stroke width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, shapes, stroke

I created a rectangle shape in order to use it as list item background. My problem is the stroke does not follow the view border but let a margin of +/- the stroke width.

Here is the xml of my shape :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="1"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/deminoir" />
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/deminoir" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

And here is the xml of my style :

```
<style name="champ">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bordurechamp</item>
</style>
```

And finaly the xml of my list item view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/champ" >


    <!-- titre -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/deminoir"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="titre"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

    <!-- Contenu -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valeur"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="valeur"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 85):

Surround your `shape` with `<item>...</item>` tags and set up `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` attributes of `<item>` with ***margin values you want***. Then wrap whole `item` with a `<layer-list>`. See below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="{L-Margin}dp"
        android:right="{R-Margin}dp"
        android:bottom="{B-Margin}dp"
        android:top="{T-Margin}dp">

        <!-- Insert your shape here: -->
        <shape android:shape="...">  
            ...
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

---

*If you want `padding` (instead of `margin`), see [Ahmad Aghazadeh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41180439/5318303) below.*

Answer (score 12):

You can use padding Transparent instead of margin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke 
        android:width="8dp" 
        android:color="#0000000" />
    <padding 
        android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />

    <solid 
        android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 8):

I had same problem and solved it like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/background" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/background" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It gives two drawables with two strokes. First drawable have stroke with width (width + margin of desirable stroke). Second drawable have only visible stroke with width of desirable margin.