# Padding between stroke and the drawable

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I have created selector buttons using MaterialButtonToggleGroup.

I want to add padding between stroke and drawable.

This is what I’m getting:
[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

As you can see in the above image there is padding between stroke and selector drawable.

Here is the XML code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:checkedButton="@id/btnOutline"
        android:paddingVertical="4dp"
        app:selectionRequired="true"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOutline"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="@string/outline"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_color"
            app:strokeColor="@color/selector_btn_toggle" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMain"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="@string/main"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_color"
            app:strokeColor="@color/selector_btn_toggle" />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

As you can see in the code I'm using android:drawablePadding="2dp", but this is not working.
I'm using a backgroundTint to set the selector drawable.

Drawable **button_selector** code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/selector_btn_toggle" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: dont use color instead use background and create layer list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47955273/7513880)

Comment: can you post button selector xml ?

Comment: @rajan.kali it is already there "Drawable button_selector code:".

Comment: Add marginTop,marginStart, marginBottom in Outline Button, Add marginTop, marginEnd, marginBottom in Main Button of 2dp, and materialbutton group will have background with outline color background

Answer (score 0):

Create a `layer-list`, to add i`t`em padding, `drawablepPadding` works for compound `drawable` not for background, create below

**selected_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:left="3dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/selector_btn_toggle"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

then set it your `button_selectpr`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_background" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Not working. Not adding padding and also the color is not changing.